# How to print labels and column names for Confusion Matrix?

Tags: classification, python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I get the confusion matrix but since my actual data set has lot of classification categories, it's difficult to understand.

Example -

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
>>> y_test
['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'c']
>>> y_pred
['b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'c']
>>> 
>>> 
>>> confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
array([[2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

But how to print the labels/column names for better understanding?

I even tried this -

```
>>> pd.factorize(y_test)
(array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 0, 2], dtype=int64), array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], dtype=object))
>>> pd.factorize(y_pred)
(array([0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2], dtype=int64), array(['b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e'], dtype=object))
```

Any help please?

Comment: [The docs for `confusion_matrix`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) say under the `labels` argument: _If none is given, those that appear at least once in `y_true` or `y_pred` are used in sorted order._ So the labels are just `a b c d e`, in order.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
y_test = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'c']
y_pred = ['b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'c']


labels = np.unique(y_test)
a =  confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred, labels=labels)

pd.DataFrame(a, index=labels, columns=labels)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c  d  e
a  2  1  0  0  0
b  0  1  0  0  0
c  0  0  2  0  0
d  1  0  0  1  0
e  0  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: Hi Scott, I've continued the next bit of question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54891276/display-columns-and-labels-for-confusion-matrix

Comment: @ranit.b irrespectively of any follow-up question, since the present answer resolved your issue and delivered exactly what you requested, kindly *accept* it

Comment: Sure @desertnaut. Initially had marked it helpful, but have accepted as well now. Thanks. (Still a newbie on SO; just learning.)